# node.js see files in folder instead of app

Tags: node.js, npm

very new to nodejs, tried to build a very simple server on a linux server. for some reason when I go to the url I see the files in the folder. I am learning so I created a folder for each learning exercise.

This is my code: 
   server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var port = 3000;

var app = express();


app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.send('About Page');
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started on ports '+port);

module.exports = app;
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "myexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple express application",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "body-parser":"*"
  }
}
```

I run `node server` in the folder project, I receive the `Server running on ports3000` massage but in the browser[image] i see this:

any help could be great,

Comment: What URL are you visiting in the browser?

Comment: your code seems perfect, have u tried to remove `module.exports = app;`,  however the existing code should work

Comment: this is the url: seveloff.com/node1

Comment: You need to visit `http://localhost:3000` in the browser. You are running this on your local machine, right?

Comment: no, not in a local machine, in a live server.

Comment: now i did sow some activity, `Server started on ports 3000
Time:  1496122514888
Time:  1496122515244
`

Comment: Your app is running at `http://seveloff.com:3000`

Comment: I get an error "This site can’t be reached". by the way, is it possible to run more than one node app on a server?

Comment: You can technically run different node apps on different ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are visiting an URL like

```
http://localhost/yourprojectfolder
```

That's why it is showing the folder index. If it's a local project, then visit

```
http://localhost:3000 //3000 your port number
```

Otherwise visit your server's URL

```
http://example.com:3000
```